# Sequel::RecordNotFound exception on find_or_create

Tags: ruby, sequel

I would expect that `find_or_create` would return nil if there's no record and pass a block to create one.

```
Sequel::RecordNotFound: Sequel::RecordNotFound
    from /RubyProjects/platform/lib/sequel/plugins/railsify.rb:48:in `find'
    from /RubyProjects/platform/lib/sequel/plugins/railsify.rb:69:in `find'
    from /.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sequel-3.43.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:331:in `find_or_create'
```

using:

```
m = SAM::My_Model.find_or_create(:name => "foo") do |ds|
    ds.organization = "Bar"
    ds.name = "foo"
    ds.remote_id = SAM::My_model::SOURCE_ID
end
```